# Is there a way to send params inside params in ajax call (vanillaJS)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

**The context**

I'm building a save/load system for an email template builder based on grapesjs-mjml. I'm saving my MJML code in a BDD (MySQL).

**My current code**

I'm sending my template name and my template MJML code through an ajax call which look like that

```
let params = "name="+template_name + "&html="+template_mjml;
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", "save.php", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    // doing stuffs when it's saved
  }
};
xhttp.send(params);
```

and on the server side, I'm catching the `html` value with a standard `$_POST['html']`

**My issue**

Sometimes, there is urls inside my `html` param (it could be links for example). And inside those urls, there is some `&` which means my `$_POST['html']` is not reading the whole param: it's stopping right before the first `&` of my `html` code

**My dirty solution**

On my client side, I added a `html = html.replaceAll('&','//amp;')` and I'm doing the reverse function on the server side. Which that, I'm getting rid of all `&` in my 'html' param, but it's not very nice...

I would like to know if one of you know a better/nicer solution to do that ?

Comment: See the linked question's answers. You *always* have to encode URI values, for instance with `encodeURIComponent`. In fact, keys need to be encoded too, but if you know the key doesn't have any characters that encoding will change (`name` and `html` don't, for instance), you can skip it.

Comment: Encode and decode your data before and after the request. Encode it on your ajax call using `encodeURI()` and decide in php using `htmlspecialchars_decode()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [**`encodeURIComponent()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent). This will properly encode special characters.

```
let params = "name=" + encodeURIComponent(template_name) + "&html=" + encodeURIComponent(template_mjml);
```

Comment: Hum... I already tried that and it was not working and now it works... Thank you for your answer !